# Validate BaseX XML database against XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, basex

I need to apply some rules to my xml-database in BaseX (like unique element-values).
BaseX offers a command to check if a xml file is valid given a xsd-scheme file. But how to apply it to a database (or how to get the path of the xml-file backed by baseX)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do something like that (see [Validation Module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Validation_Module#validate:xsd) for more details):

```
for $doc in db:open('db')
return validate:xsd($doc, 'schema.xsd')
```

Comment: is there a way to check if an update (for example an insert-query) woukd violate a xsd-rule?

Comment: Just build a main memory instance of your document and validate it before storing it in the database. This can e.g. look as follows: `let $doc := db:open('db', 'doc.xml') update (delete node .//text()) return (validate:xsd($doc, 'schema.xsd'), db:replace('db', 'doc.xml', $doc)'